# Zonal statistics with rasterstats: "Invalid out_shape, must be 2D" (Python)

Tags: python, raster, rasterstats

I'm trying to produce zonal statistics (summing pixel values representing population estimates by polygons), roughly following [GeoDelta Labs (19:20 onwards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIr-pejky6E). A `ValueError "Invalid out_shape, must be 2D"` is raised for the `zonal_stats` function, though.

Below my code and the full error log.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterstats import zonal_stats, gen_zonal_stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define study area to be applied to raster window
states = gpd.read_file('my.shp')
study_area = states[states['FIELD'] == 'Value X']
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = study_area.total_bounds

# Load municipal boundaries and filter those falling within study area
municipal_all = gpd.read_file('....shp')
municipal_filter = municipal_all[municipal_all['FIELD'] == 'Value X']

# Load raster to extent of study area
# Source: CIESIN HRSL: https://ciesin.columbia.edu/data/hrsl/#data

with rio.open('...tif') as dataset:

    top, lft = dataset.index(xmin, ymax) 
    bot, rgt = dataset.index(xmax, ymin)
    pop_array = dataset.read(window=((top, bot), (lft, rgt)))

    affine = dataset.transform

    # CALCULATING ZONAL STATS

    municipal_pop_sum = zonal_stats(municipal_filter, pop_array, affine=affine, stats=['sum'], geojson_out=True)
```

**Error log**

```
import numpy as np...
C:\Users\...\envs\xxx\lib\site-packages\rasterstats\io.py:301: UserWarning: Setting nodata to -999; specify nodata explicitly
  warnings.warn("Setting nodata to -999; specify nodata explicitly")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\...\script.py in 
     48     # CALCULATING ZONAL STATS
     49 
---> 50     municipal_pop_sum = zonal_stats(municipal_filter, pop_array, affine=affine, stats=['sum'], geojson_out=True)
     51 
     52 """

~\anaconda3\envs\xxx\lib\site-packages\rasterstats\main.py in zonal_stats(*args, **kwargs)
     29     The only difference is that ``zonal_stats`` will
     30     return a list rather than a generator."""
---> 31     return list(gen_zonal_stats(*args, **kwargs))
     32 
     33 

~\anaconda3\envs\xxx\lib\site-packages\rasterstats\main.py in gen_zonal_stats(vectors, raster, layer, band, nodata, affine, stats, all_touched, categorical, category_map, add_stats, zone_func, raster_out, prefix, geojson_out, **kwargs)
    157 
    158             # rasterized geometry
--> 159             rv_array = rasterize_geom(geom, like=fsrc, all_touched=all_touched)
    160 
    161             # nodata mask

~\anaconda3\envs\xxx\lib\site-packages\rasterstats\utils.py in rasterize_geom(geom, like, all_touched)
     39     """
     40     geoms = [(geom, 1)]
---> 41     rv_array = features.rasterize(
     42         geoms,
     43         out_shape=like.shape,

~\anaconda3\envs\xxx\lib\site-packages\rasterio\env.py in wrapper(*args, **kwds)
    382     def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
    383         if local._env:
--> 384             return f(*args, **kwds)
    385         else:
    386             with Env.from_defaults():

~\anaconda3\envs\xxx\lib\site-packages\rasterio\features.py in rasterize(shapes, out_shape, fill, out, transform, all_touched, merge_alg, default_value, dtype)
    343 
    344         if len(out_shape) != 2:
--> 345             raise ValueError('Invalid out_shape, must be 2D')
    346 
    347         out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype)

ValueError: Invalid out_shape, must be 2D
```

**What worked**

The types for the inputs to `zonal_stats` are what I think is expected according to the [manual](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/manual.html#vector-data-sources), i.e. first a GeoDataFrame (`municipal_filtered`, with a shape of (20, 17)), then an nd array (`pop_array`, with a shape of (1, 1179, 5935)), and the `affine`. Is the issue the third dimension for the array here, meaning I should somehow remove it?

Changing `zonal_stats` to `gen_zonal_stats` works, though I'm not sure what to do with the resulting generator object.

Displaying both the `pop_array` (via `imshow()`) and the polygons (via `add_feature`) on the same figure in matplotlib also works fine.

**My system**

I'm running Python 3.8.8. Installed rasterstats today via Anaconda so I presume all the latest dependencies are there.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out with some kind help :)

I needed to specifically define the band when reading the array from the source raster (even when there's only 1 band)

```
array = dataset.read(1)
```